# How to delete all files of multiple extensions with brace expansion unix?

Tags: unix, curly-braces, expansion

What am i getting wrong here?

I'm trying to move all the `.json` and `.py` from `/home/myname/foo/` to `/home/myname/foo/`.

I've tried, while in directory `myname`,
`mv ./foo/{*.json, *.py} ./bar/`
as well ass 
`mv ./foo/*{.json, .py} ./bar/`,

but to no avail. Would love to learn how to use the expansion correctly of course more than to move the files. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the space.  Either `./foo/*.{json,py}` or `./foo/*{.json,.py}` should work.

Or, simpler but slightly longer, `mv ./foo/*.json ./foo/*.py ./bar`.